# Matlab plotting specific points on x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to plot a function with markers where f(x)=0.
I have a function `findmanyzeros` that returns an array of x-values where f(x)=0 within a range.
For example:

```
findmanyzeros(@(x)sin(x)-exp(-x), 0, 10, 50, 1e-10);
ans = [0.5885 3.0964 6.2850 9.4247]
```

I am trying to plot the graph of f(x) and the zeros of f(x) that lie on the x-axis, but when I run the code below the resulting figure does not display the zeros.
How can I properly display the zeros of f(x) along the x-axis?
Also, how can I do it such that I'm not hardcoding the amount of values (`[ 0 0 0 0]`)?

```
% Find zeros of f(x)
f = @(x)sin(x)-exp(-x);
zeros = findmanyzeros(f, 0, 10, 50, 1e-10);

% Plot f(x)
fplot(f, [0 10], 'linewidth', 2, 'color', 'b');
hold on

% Plot the x-axis
yline(0, 'linewidth', 2, 'color', 'r');
hold on

% Plot the zeros of f(x)
plot(zeros, [0 0 0 0], 'color', 'g', 'MarkerSize',20);
hold off

grid on
ylim([-1.5 1])
```

[image: Plot of f(x) without zeros showing up]

EDIT: I want my figure to look like this:
[image: Plot of f(x) with correct components]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is strongly recommended avoiding naming variables with names of existing functions, so calling your values vector **"zeros"** isn't a good idea, and you'll be better off with calling it **"my_func_zeros"** or something similar. [**zeros**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) is a built-in matlab function used to create zeros-filled vectors/matrices.

As for your questions:

1. I believe you've just forgot to specify **what** type of marker you want, so by default it's an infinitely small point which won't appear.  Further more, when using one of MATLAB's basic colors\markers, there is no need to specify the option name (will be more clear in the code line I'll attach).
2. You can use the function **zeros** and [**length**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html?searchHighlight=length&s_tid=srchtitle) to create a vector with a dependent size.

Therefor, your code should look somewhat like this:

```
my_func_zeros = findmanyzeros(f, 0, 10, 50, 1e-10);
...
plot(my_func_zeros, zeros(1,length(my_func_zeros)), '*g', 'MarkerSize',20);
```

where:

> zeros(1,length(my_func_zeros))

creates a vector containing zeros with the size of your my_func_zeros vector, and:

> '*g'

specifies the marker type (*) and the color (g).

By the way, there is no need to add `hold on` after every plot - after you wrote it once anything you plot will be plotted on the same figure until the next `hold off` or `figure` command.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. After implementing your changes my figure still appears the same. I commented out all calls to `plot` except for `plot(my_func_zeros, zeros(1,length(my_func_zeros)), '*g', 'MarkerSize',20);` in case there was some overlapping, but this resulted in an empty figure.

Comment: Hi!
That's weird, I checked it on my device.

Can you attach the entire current code?